# Node.js: "Access is denied"

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a simple node.js app in VS Code.
All im trying to do is:

```
const name = "Tom";
console.log("Hello " + name);
```

When I run the code, I get the error: `Program 'node.exe' failed to run: Access is denied`.
When I try to check Node is installed with `node -v` in windows cmd, it also says "Access is denied".
How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Check if the node is registered on system environment variables.

Comment: I don't that's the issue as with `environment variables issue` it generally throws error `node is not found as external or internal command`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough permission to execute node commands in CMD, to solve this

Run `CMD` as an Admin

Comment: When I did `node -v` in cmd as Administrator, it still said "Access is denied"

Answer (score 1):

1. Type cmd on your start menu
2. Right click on the "Command Prompt" menu item and select "Open file Location"
3. Right click on the file and select properties.
4. Go to "Advanced" and select "Run as Administrator" and Ok.

[image]

If this doesn't solve your problem -

1. Go to the "Security" tab.
2. Click "Edit"
3. Add "Everyone" and Ok

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way that worked for me (Windows 10) was the following:

1. Open "nodejs" folder location
2. Right-click + R
3. Open "Security tab" + "Advanced"
4. Change Owner to "Administrator".
5. Add permissions for Administrator "Full control"
6. Tick "Replace all child objects permission entries..."
7. "Ok". Save

✅ Done

Answer (score 0):

use command prompt instead of powershell in windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using NVM and in admin mode CMD when I selected version `nvm list` and `nvm use version_goes_here` and did `npm i` and it worked like a charm I hope it helped you or anyone reading this. :)

Answer (score -1):

Add "**cd**" before your directory name in cmd.

**Ex**:  **cd** C:\Users..\js **folder** name(**not the filename**)

and then type "**dir**" in cmd.

**Ex**:  **dir**

you will get a list of files present in that folder,And then just enter "**node jsfilename**"

**[Ex][2]**: **node** jsfilename

now you will have the desired output in cmd.

I think Access Denied happened because your root directory was different than the file's root directory that's why we used "cd" change directory, and to view the files present in the current directory we used "dir". Then we opened the js
file with node "node jsfilename".I hope You Got it.I believe you can see the image I have Attached below.

**Refer To this image below:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oibrF.jpg

Comment: You forgot to attach the image

Comment: Yeah Thanks . I have added it now!