# Node.js: Access Denied

Tags: node.js, windows-installer, access-denied

Just installed node.js on Windows 10 via msi installer.
Any command results to access denied error.

```
PS D:\sasha\Angular\ExampleShop> node -v
Сбой выполнения программы node.exe: Отказано в доступестрока:1 знак:1
+ node -v
+ ~~~~~~~.
строка:1 знак:1
+ node -v
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: Probably your question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507724/node-js-access-is-denied

Comment: Running command prompt as Administrator does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, resolved the issue by myself. I changed Owner of the folder in which I installed node.js to my domain account.